Can I add a custom workout for my companion app?
I've recently developed a workout companion watch app for iOS. However, I'm now have a task of implementing custom workouts for my app.
I've come across a video demonstrating how to create and schedule custom workouts for the watch app, which I believe will be incredibly helpful for my project.
Video Link: Creating Custom Workouts for iOS Watch App
If anyone knows of any additional resources, such as articles or videos, that further explores this topic, I would greatly appreciate it if you could share them with me.
Thank you for your assistance!

I'm afraid this forum-style question is not for SO, you trying to start a discussion asking for tutorial recommendations, but Stackoverflow is about very specific problems and solutions.
